# Usergrid Build Error, Error in opening zip file

Tags: maven, usergrid

while I'm trying to build Usergrid, I'm coming across the following error.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-core/1.9.1/jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-  grizzly2/1.11/jersey-grizzly2-1.11.jar; error in opening zip file
[INFO] 2 errors
```

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Remove those jars so that maven re-downloads them. They may be corrupted.